# Scala Build Tools and Neo4J Http API CORS error

Tags: scala, neo4j, scala.js

I am trying to access my neo4j database in my sbt application using scala.js. I am trying to access the database through the HTTP API, but I am getting
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7474/db/data' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`
So far my code is :

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:7474/db/data")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
xhr.onload = { (e: dom.Event) =>
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    println(xhr)
  }
}
xhr.send()
```

I've tried manipulating the headers based on feedback from forums but nothing has worked. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try setting also this: xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

Comment: @mfirry thanks for the help! Unfortunately,it is still throwing the CORS error. I'll update my answer to reflect the addition

Comment: Looks like neo4j cors settings also needs to be updated

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan agreed but how to do this remains an open question.